# jQuery Validate plugin: Can using the "depends" tag return an int?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Here is an example of a rule declaration in my rules object:

```
myFieldObj: {
    maxlength: {
      depends: function(element) {
        if($("#intranetApplication").is(":checked") == true) {
            return 32;
          }
        else if($("#internetApplication").is(":checked") == true) {
            return 25;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Basically, my code is setting the max length of myFieldObj to be validated based on the user choice of a certain question.  However, this code does not seem to work.  I know I can return Boolean values using this code (e.g):

```
myFieldObj: {
    maxlength: {
      depends: function(element) {
        if($("#intranetApplication").is(":checked") == true) {
            return TRUE;
          }
        else if($("#internetApplication").is(":checked") == true) {
            return FALSE;
          }
       }
    }
}
```

But does this work for integers as well?

Comment: Show just enough code to construct a working demo... too much is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `depends` property and use the function as the method's parameter...

```
myFieldObj: {
    maxlength: function(element) {
        if ($("#intranetApplication").is(":checked")) {
            return 32;
        }
        else if ($("#internetApplication").is(":checked")) {
            return 25;
        }
    }
}
```

Also since [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) already returns a boolean, there's no need to compare it to `true`.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/931ach1g/](http://jsfiddle.net/931ach1g/)**